# Equivalent of Bstr Wrapper of c# in vc++

Tags: c#, visual-c++

what is the equivalent of BstrWrapper of c# in vc++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ATL has the quite handy [`CComBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) class. However, ATL comes only with the paid versions of VS.

There's also the compiler COM support class [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx).

And you can directly use the Win32 [`string manipulation functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221105.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In Win32 `BSTR`, other libraries might provide wrappers of this primitive type.